# Placement of Previous and Next Buttons?

Tags: placement, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Button order Save | Save and next | Cancel | Previous](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20525/button-order-save-save-and-next-cancel-previous)

I have a Form widget with Five Step. Steps 2-3-4 having previous and next and cancel button. Step 1 having next and cancel button and step 5 having Previous Save Save and Repeat and Cancel button. I am worried about placement of these buttons on the form widget.

Comment: how does it look it, the layout? can you post it?

Comment: This question might have been answered already. Search for 'previous next' or 'button alignment'.

Comment: As per one school of thought, you should place all negative targets like cancel away from your positive responses. So depending on your layout (web form vs desktop based dialog wizard) you should separate cancel, previous from next, save, save and repeat in groups with appropriate layouts.
As sree mentioned, sharing your layout will help in getting better response.

Comment: See [Should the okay/cancel buttons be right aligned or centered?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37/should-the-ok-cancel-buttons-be-aligned-right-or-centered?rq=1) I'm thinking this is a duplicate but it's very hard to tell without a picture

Comment: common solution withouе knowing details could be button "Prev" on left border of widget and button "Next" on the right respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as possible you want to keep the buttons in the same location on each page. So step 1 could just have two buttons "cancel" and "next" - right justified, and then steps 2, 3 and 4 could have three buttons "previous", "cancel" and "next" - again justified right.

By keeping the locations basically the same the user is less likely to click the wrong action at each stage. For example they can keep their mouse at the same location and click "Next", "Next", ... "Save" and complete the action. By keeping "Cancel" in the same place they will always know where to go to abort the whole process.

Step 5 is a little more problematical because it has the extra "save and repeat" button. To keep the buttons as close to the bottom as possible you'd have to leave space for the "repeat" button thus moving the buttons away from the right hand edge. However, if you keep the buttons as close as possible to the right hand edge you'd have to have the "repeat" button on another line. Neither approach is ideal.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Q4Ht.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: What is your layout assumption? why step 5 has to be like that? please share your assumption...

Comment: @sree - I'm not 100% happy with step 5 and was thinking of revising it. The goal was to keep the buttons as close to the bottom left as possible.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I was actually reading cjforms slideshare which has created much of the confusion http://www.slideshare.net/cjforms/buttons-on-forms-and-surveys-a-look-at-some-research-2012

Comment: Also here in her theory Save Should appear before Cancel and Next Should appear before Previous. So this becomes more confusing.

Comment: @sushilbharwani - my point is that the buttons should be one the same place at each step, the order *could* be altered, but I think the one I present is more logical.

Comment: @ChrisF tnx, glad u made some changes :)

Comment: @Sushil: You need to read the slides carefully. As far as I understand (without hearing the talk to the slides) she starts with the (known) recommendation to align action buttons with the input fields. Then she moves on to test this with previous and next buttons, leading to the "surprise layout" were next comes before previous and is aligned with input. _Then_ she quotes studies that show users being confused by the order and summarizes that the recommended alignment should not mess up established expectations.

Comment: @Louise thanks for the explanation. I really appreciate.